# Get all attributes of extraFields in Yii2

Tags: api, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-api

To get attribute from extraFields() url is like

```
 organizations/6/location?expands=address,city (i have 10 attribute)
```

But how can i get all these at once from extraFields()

something like this organizations/6/location?expands=true or all

This contoller

```
public function actionIndex($id) {
   $locations= Location::findAll($id);

    return new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $locations,

        'pagination' => false,
    ]);
```

And this is my Model code

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'id',
        'display',
    ];
}

public function extraFields() {
    return [
        'address',
        'city',
        'state',
        'country',
        'zipcode',
        'country_code',
        'phone_number',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question, but i think you want to do that :

organizations/6/location?expands=true&address=myadresse&city=mycity ....

Can you give us some code to help you ?

Comment: Now check my question @Jonathan Delean

Comment: You dev the API or you try to use it ? can you provide us the code of your backend and your front end ?

Comment: I am developing api

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the URL, it should be

`expand=address,city` not `expandS=address,city`

See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources#overriding-extra-fields